# Associativity of operators

Tags: c#, language-lawyer

In the C# specification is said:

> Except for the assignment operators and the null coalescing operator,
>   all binary operators are left-associative, meaning that operations are
>   performed from left to right.
>
> The assignment operators, the null coalescing operator and the
>   conditional operator (?:) are right-associative, meaning that
>   operations are performed from right to left.

that's enough clear but operators like `default`, `delegate`, `stackalloc`, `await` how they are classified? Which is their associativity?

The same can be said for `[]`, `()`, e.g; are they unary or binary or technically none of them because according the standard unary operator is something like *op x* while binary operator is something like *x op y*?

Comment: None of the "operators" you mention are binary.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. Can you provide an example of code where you're unsure of the result?

Comment: @JonSkeet Isn't it weird it unders on `Primary Operators` seciton in [C# Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) page?

Comment: @SonerGönül: Very odd. Checking elsewhere now... Maybe I'm just wrong.

Comment: I see it's in the C# 5 spec and the ECMA standard, too. Hmm. Yup, I think I'm just wrong. Deleting my first comment :)

Comment: I *thought* this wasn't relevant, but I'm beginning to think it might be. Thinking more :)

Comment: @Hamidi, if they are not binary but are unary then they must associate form right to left but that is not the case. In fact [], () associate left-to-right. So here it my doubt according to C# terminology. Again that's not clear and that's not said the associativity of await, default, etc. How can we categorize them?

Comment: @xdevel2000: `a[x]` and `f(x)` are binary operators. But the problem remains with some unary ones.

Comment: @JonSkeet, why are they binary? where is the equiv "x op y"?

Comment: `a` and `x` for indexing, and `f` and `x` for function invocation. In each case, there are two operands - the value you're working with, and the argument list for the method/indexing call. Note that in this case the syntax stops some of the potential ambiguity anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet, almost all clear... however my doubt are still on operators keyword like default, await, etc. How can we know associativity? The spec says nothing about these operators...

Comment: @xdevel2000: See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem here, because all the non-primary unary operators have the same precedence as each other, and a different precedence to all *binary* operators. Associativity comes into effect when an operand is between two operators of the same precedence - but an operand can't be between two non-primary unary operators.

All the *primary* unary operators (`new`, `typeof`, `default`, `checked`, `unchecked` and `delegate`) have syntax rules which mean they're not a problem - basically, you can tell the operand by where the parenthese/braces are. Without the parentheses, there could be a problem. For example, supposed the `unchecked` operator didn't require parentheses. Then this:

```
unchecked x . y
```

could mean `unchecked(x.y)` or `(unchecked x).y` without more rules. It's not a problem though, as it's not valid anyway.

It's worth noting that the precedence and associativity explanations in the specification are really only informational anyway - the precise rules are encoded in the grammar of the language already. In other words, the section could be removed from the spec without affecting the validity or meaning of any program. (Good job too, as there are a couple of mistakes, IIRC...)

Comment: So for operators keyword that are primary operators like typeof, checked, etc., can we deduce that as they are used with () they are like binary operators and so associate left-to-right? The keyword await, instead, is already categorized as unary operator and then associate right-to-left (we cannot use () with it). Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @xdevel2000: Again, associativity is only relevant when there are two operators of the same precedence, such that an operand could be part of either one "first". Can you give an example of how you think that's relevant with `typeof` etc?